# Undefined symbol apr_atomic_add64

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, bsd

Im trying to install apache24 server in freeBSD 12 but when i install apache24 pkg and i add the line in rc.conf and i try to start the service y get this error: 
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EKaw.png)

Im struggling with this, i saw it could be fixed it with upgrading php package but i tried and it doesnt work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, and I just reinstalled apache24 with `pkg upgrade -f apache24`. That seemed to fix it. Maybe something installed afterwards borked one of the shared libraries or something.